# How can i replace String "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB" to "AXA OR BXB && CXC OR BXB"?

Tags: java, string, escaping, replace

How can i replace String `AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB` to `AXA OR BXB && CXC OR BXB` ?

i tried

```
expression = "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB";
expression = expression.replaceAll("||", " OR ");
```

But this doesnt provide desired result ie `AXA OR BXB && CXC OR BXB`

Comment: Are you actually trying to do the blind character substitution you specify here, or is this an attempt at parsing?

Comment: raplaceAll uses a regex, and `|` is a special caracter, try doing string `expression.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "OR");`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using regular expressions, try the `replace` routine instead

```
expression = "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB";
expression = expression.replace("||", " OR ");
```

Comment: @Pshemo, You're right, although underneath it *still* compiles a [`Pattern`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) object. Otherwise [`StringUtils.replace(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) is a good alternative.

Comment: You're right, it `replace(char,char)` escapes regex. I removed my previous comment since it was false info.

Answer (score 1):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses a regex, and `|` is a special character, which means *alternation*. Thus, you need to *escape* it in order to use a literal `|`:

```
String s = "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "OR"));
```

Or better yet, just use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which doesn't use a regex:

```
String s = "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB";
System.out.println(s.replace("||", "OR"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression as its first argument, try using `replace` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) here, which treats the pattern as a regex. Use [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) and you don't have to worry about escaping [special characters in the pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical).

```
expression = "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB";
expression = expression.replace("||", " OR ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape out the `|`

```
String expression = "AXA || BXB && CXC || BXB";
expression = expression.replaceAll(" ?\\|\\| ?", " OR ");
System.out.println(expression);
```

prints

```
AXA OR BXB && CXC OR BXB
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to forget what all the special characters are in regular expressions.  I'm now in the habit of using [`String Pattern.quote(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) around any literal I want to include that has any non-alphanumeric characters in it.

(If this case is as simple as you describe, I agree that replace() is the better choice.)